# JUnit tests stuck

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, spring-test

The problem occurred after upgrade Spring Boot project to 3.01 and Java to 17. Also the pom.xml has been changed a lot. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to set all the version numbers manually, but the guy who did it, had some problems to get the dependencies work.
Now, I'm not able to run a JUnit test anymore, because it stucks after booting the framework. The test methods are not called. It doesn't matter, if I start the test from Intellij or from command line. I'm using the annotation @SpringBootTest in my tests.
In Intellij you can see, that Spring Boot framework is up, but the test method is grey and never runs. The test never finishes.

[image]

To change the Maven implemention, also had no effect. Locally I'm using Maven 3.8.3. To start Maven with 'mvn -X test' also didn't help.
I appreciate every hint.

Example test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class TaskCreateXPlanTest {
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskCreateXPlanTest.class);

    @Test
    void test() {
        
        logger.info("Start!");
        logger.info("End!");

    }

}
```

**UPDATE new pom.xml (problem still exists):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tool</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.12</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Tool</name>
    <description>new</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        
        <!-- Jackson and XML/Excel -->
<!--        <jackson-version>2.14.1</jackson-version>-->
<!--        <jackson-databind-version>2.14.1</jackson-databind-version>-->
        <jackson-databind-nullable-version>0.2.4</jackson-databind-nullable-version>
        <jackson-threetenbp-version>2.12.5</jackson-threetenbp-version>
<!--        <javax-servlet-version>4.0.1</javax-servlet-version>-->
<!--        <jakarta-servlet-version>6.0.0</jakarta-servlet-version>-->
<!--        <jakarta-annotation-version>2.1.1</jakarta-annotation-version>-->
        <jxls-version>2.12.0</jxls-version>
        
        <!-- Google Libraries -->
        <gson-version>2.10.1</gson-version>
        <gson-fire-version>1.8.5</gson-fire-version>
        <google-findbugs-version>3.0.2</google-findbugs-version>
        
        <!-- DB and Building Libraries -->
        <h2-database-version>2.1.214</h2-database-version>
<!--        <maven-resources-plugin-version>3.3.0</maven-resources-plugin-version>      -->
<!--        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>-->
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        
        <!-- Apache Libraries -->
        <apache-commons-version>1.9.0</apache-commons-version>
        <commons-io-version>2.11.0</commons-io-version>
        <apache-poi-version>5.2.3</apache-poi-version>
        <apache-commons-lang-version>3.12.0</apache-commons-lang-version>
        
        <!-- Spring and related Libraries -->
<!--        <spring-latest-version>3.0.1</spring-latest-version>-->
<!--        <spring-thymeleaf-version>3.0.1</spring-thymeleaf-version>-->
<!--        <spring-security-version>6.0.1</spring-security-version>-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;        <spring-web-version>6.0.3</spring-web-version> &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <spring-thymeleaf-extras-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-thymeleaf-extras-version>-->
        <springdoc-openapi-ui-version>1.6.14</springdoc-openapi-ui-version>
        
        <!-- other libraries and newer versions of spring contained libraries -->
        <json-webtoken-version>0.11.5</json-webtoken-version>
        <lingala-zip4j-version>2.11.3</lingala-zip4j-version>
        <schegge-holidays-version>0.1.7</schegge-holidays-version>
        <snakeyaml-version>1.33</snakeyaml-version>
        <aerogear-otp-version>1.0.0</aerogear-otp-version>
<!--        <org-lombok-version>1.18.24</org-lombok-version>-->
        <itext-pdf-version>5.5.13.3</itext-pdf-version>
        <itext-html2pdf-version>4.0.4</itext-html2pdf-version>
        
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Spring Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring-web-version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-thymeleaf-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-thymeleaf-extras-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Spring Security Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- validation -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${snakeyaml-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
<!--            <version>${h2-database-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${org-lombok-version}</version>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-commons-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${apache-commons-lang-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-threetenbp-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jakarta-servlet-version}</version>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${jakarta-annotation-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        

        
        <!--  Working with Excel -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>${jxls-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls-poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>${jxls-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>${google-findbugs-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${gson-version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json Webtoken Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Holidayserving Library for XPlan-Creation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.schegge</groupId>
            <artifactId>holidays</artifactId>
            <version>${schegge-holidays-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Imports for Housekeeping and Monthplan serving -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>${lingala-zip4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext-pdf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext-html2pdf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        <!-- 2-Factor Authentication Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>${aerogear-otp-version}</version>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<!--              <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>-->
              <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>${maven-resources-plugin-version}</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

old pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tool</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.12</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Tool</name>
    <description>new</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        
        <!-- Jackson and XML/Excel -->
        <jackson-version>2.14.1</jackson-version>
        <jackson-databind-version>2.14.1</jackson-databind-version>
        <jackson-databind-nullable-version>0.2.4</jackson-databind-nullable-version>
        <jackson-threetenbp-version>2.12.5</jackson-threetenbp-version>
        <javax-annotation-version>1.3.2</javax-annotation-version>
        <javax-servlet-version>4.0.1</javax-servlet-version>
        <jakarta-servlet-version>6.0.0</jakarta-servlet-version>
        <jakarta-annotation-version>2.1.1</jakarta-annotation-version>
        <jxls-version>2.12.0</jxls-version>
        
        <!-- Google Libraries -->
        <gson-version>2.10.1</gson-version>
        <gson-fire-version>1.8.5</gson-fire-version>
        <google-findbugs-version>3.0.2</google-findbugs-version>
        
        <!-- DB and Building Libraries -->
        <h2-database-version>2.1.214</h2-database-version>
        <maven-resources-plugin-version>3.3.0</maven-resources-plugin-version>      
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        
        <!-- Apache Libraries -->
        <apache-commons-version>1.9.0</apache-commons-version>
        <commons-io-version>2.11.0</commons-io-version>
        <apache-poi-version>5.2.3</apache-poi-version>
        <apache-commons-lang-version>3.12.0</apache-commons-lang-version>
        
        <!-- Spring and related Libraries -->
        <spring-latest-version>3.0.1</spring-latest-version>
        <spring-thymeleaf-version>3.0.1</spring-thymeleaf-version>
        <spring-security-version>6.0.1</spring-security-version>
<!--        <spring-web-version>6.0.3</spring-web-version> -->
        <spring-thymeleaf-extras-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-thymeleaf-extras-version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui-version>1.6.14</springdoc-openapi-ui-version>
        
        <!-- other libraries and newer versions of spring contained libraries -->
        <json-webtoken-version>0.11.5</json-webtoken-version>
        <lingala-zip4j-version>2.11.3</lingala-zip4j-version>
        <schegge-holidays-version>0.1.7</schegge-holidays-version>
        <snakeyaml-version>1.33</snakeyaml-version>
        <aerogear-otp-version>1.0.0</aerogear-otp-version>
        <org-lombok-version>1.18.24</org-lombok-version>
        <itext-pdf-version>5.5.13.3</itext-pdf-version>
        <itext-html2pdf-version>4.0.4</itext-html2pdf-version>
        
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Spring Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring-web-version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-thymeleaf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-thymeleaf-extras-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Spring Security Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- validation -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-latest-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>${h2-database-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org-lombok-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-commons-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-commons-lang-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-threetenbp-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta-servlet-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta-annotation-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        

        
        <!--  Working with Excel -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>${jxls-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls-poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>${jxls-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>${google-findbugs-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json Webtoken Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${json-webtoken-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Holidayserving Library for XPlan-Creation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.schegge</groupId>
            <artifactId>holidays</artifactId>
            <version>${schegge-holidays-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Imports for Housekeeping and Monthplan serving -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>${lingala-zip4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext-pdf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext-html2pdf-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        <!-- 2-Factor Authentication Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>${aerogear-otp-version}</version>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you use junit4 or 5 annotations?

Comment: Most important if you work with spring-boot.. Use the spring-boot-dependencies bom file and do not define all versions all these things on your own.. Let the BOM file do the work... also for jackson etc. the same... (see the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.import) also for JWT there is spring-security-* ?? First testing is always on plain command line... etc...

Comment: Ah BTW: I haven't seen that you are already using the spring-boot-parent...than I'm asking more why do you define the deps on your own? Remove the versions for all parts with spring-... etc. jackson etc. Check the parent...if you like to have more recent versions use more recent version of spring boot (3.0.2)...Why using javax annotation? Spring 3 uses jakarta annotation etc. please read the docs about Spring Boot 3.X

Comment: @khmarbaise: Thanks for your comments. I changed pom.xml and use spring-boot-parent were it is possible. I also use spring-boot version 3.02. The problem still exists. Do you know in which file the process is logged? Is it maven log. IntelliJ log has no infos about that problem. (javax annotation was an old entry from spring-boot 2.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no general problem. Some code in the main Application class led into a continuous loop.

I was able to find the problem, by using the "Get Thread Dump" button of the debugger (IntelliJ).

[image]